# Android Firebase Remove Query Listener from DatabaseReference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have a `DatabaseReference`, get a `Query` from it, and then add a listener to that `Query`, do I have to call `removeEventListener` on the `Query` reference, or can I remove it from the original `DatabaseReference`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to use the exact same instance of DatabaseReference or Query that you used to add the listener.  A Query derived from a DatabaseReference is not at all the same thing as the DatabaseReference itself - they represent different sets of data.

Comment: If you have documentation (or unobfuscated code ;) ) supporting this, I'll give you the answer.

Comment: This is the closest thing you're looking for, but to be honest, it's generally understood that you always remove from exactly the same thing that you used to add.  Think of it like a collection.  You don't remove something from a different collection where it was added.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#detach_listeners

Comment: Works for me. Would be nice to get some closure from a Firebase member though.

Comment: I am, indeed, on the Firebase team.  I do a lot of the Android-related videos and blogs.